# Android setting the visibility of main activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Is it possible to set the visibility of the MainActivity page in android to invisible or make it transparent may be? I have tried setting the visibility to invisible and also made height width as 0dp but this still shows the mainactivity with a white background and blue header.
What I am trying to achieve is, I am opening a floating window which is draggable on click of a button in the mainactivity, but I want to directly open the floating window by triggering the button click from the code itself. This works but the mainactivity still shows up for a second before the floating window is opened. I want to make the mainactivity page invisible or transparent so the mainactivity page is not noticeable.
Here is the XML of mainactivity.xml ,

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:visibility="Invisible"
android:background="@color/material_on_primary_disabled"
tools:context="com.example.widget_android.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/open_widget"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Open Widget" />
```

on click of open_widget(which is triggered from code rather than the user having to click on it) the floating window is opened up.
I want to take the user directly to the floating window rather than the landing page which is the mainactivity page.

Here is what is happening on the backend java code

```
findViewById(R.id.open_widget).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,WidgetService.class));
            finish();
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.open_widget).performClick();
```

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for questions/problems related to the Android Studio product. Your question is a generic Android question and has nothing to do with the Android Studio product.

Comment: Also, you should edit your question and post the relevant parts of your layout file. Of course you can use a transparent background if you want. It isn't clear what you are trying to do or what you have already tried. Show us more details.

Comment: Have edited my question, please check it out and hope you can help. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why don't you just start your `Service` in `onCreate()` of your `Activity` and then call `finish()`?

Comment: Yes you are right, i have removed the button click and placed the code in onCreate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get a white screen is because that is the default behaviour. You've tried to put an invisible, transparent, or non-existing (size of 0 pixels) `View` on top of the default `View`, so you are still seeing the default `View`. What you need to do is to replace the default `View` with a transparent `View`.

See [How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-do-i-create-a-transparent-activity-on-android) for information on how to get a transparent `Activity`.

Comment: I haven't been able to get the translucent style working on my layout after trying out the solution mentioned. I may be doing something wrong. I will update you back on this. Thanks fo the pointers. This is my xml
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
    tools:context="com.example.snipper_android.MainActivity">

Comment: You've set width and height to zero! Use "match_parent" instead.

Comment: Which solution did you use? There are many different answers.

Comment: match_parent don't seem to make any difference either. I have used the same solution you have mentioned, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-do-i-create-a-transparent-activity-on-android),this one

Comment: Did you create a style and use it in the `<activity>` declaration in the manifest?

Comment: There are many different solutions mentioned in that question. Which specific solution did you use?

Comment: Yes i have created the styles.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>
</resources> and added it in mainactivity.

Comment: I tried many of the solutions mentioned there, nothing worked actually. I will try to dig a little more and update later.

Comment: did you add the theme in the `<activity>` declaration in the manifest?

Comment: Finally I was able to solve this issue by applying the translucent style to the Appcompat theme of the AndroidManifest.xml itself. Thanks for all your help @David

Comment: Glad you were able to solve this. However, I asked a question in the comments about why you are doing this. Could you respond to that question? It seems like you are doing an awful lot of unnecessary work here.

Comment: Also, if my answer was helpful you can accept it by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer. That give me some reputation points and also gets the question off the list of unanswered questions. And it will help others who have similar problems in the future.